# Dynamic $.getJSON, how do I get the elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am currently working on a page that will read in XML files that are in a directory (dynamically) and then send them back to the client via JSON. However I'm not sure how to reference the dynamic elements of the JSON array that is returned. EG.

```
$.getJSON('getfilenames.php', function(data) {
    for(var i in data)
    {
        var temp3 = data[i].name;(<-- if I dont know what .name was)
        var temp2 = temp3.replace(".xml","");
        temp = temp +'<option value="'+temp3+'">' +temp2 +'</option>';
    }
    temp = temp +'</select>';
    $("#div2").html(temp);
}
```

If I didn't already know what the .name element within data was, how could I :
A: retrieve a list of them for referencing, or B: access the data to do it myself.
I am also curious as to how I go about getting elements from within elements. EG:

```
{"contact":{"@attributes":{"id":"1"},"name":"John Doe","phone":"123-456-7890","address":"\n 123 JFKStreet\n "}}
```

How would I get the name attribute out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the properties of the returned object..

```
for (var prop in data[i]){
   // prop hold the name of the property (name) in your example
   // do something with data[i][prop]
}
```

You can go as *deep* in an object with multiple `.` notation..

from your last example (assuming the variable holding this object is `data`)

```
data.contact.name // "John Doe"
data.contact['@attributes'].id // 1 - we used the [] syntax because of @
```

Comment: So I would iterate through data to find the first set of elements, save them into an external array, then iterate through that aray (data.whateverelement[i]) until I find the data ?

Comment: You can make a function that handles a single level and use it recursively to read the whole data.. but if you are going to use the data besides dumping them on screen.. you need to know what you are looking for .. soome way to identify that you have reached the data you want..

Comment: I will only ever need to go the maximum of 2 children down, EG root, child child. (the json comes straight from an xml file), with that constraint will it be enough just to do 2 nested for statements ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Gaby ! Muchly appreciated !